# Exception in thread "main" redis.clients.jedis.exceptions.JedisNoReachableClusterNodeException: No reachable node in cluster

Tags: java, redis, jedis, redis-cluster

I am trying to connect to Redis cluster which is installed in a linux box using java to store a JSON string.

Code :

```
public JedisCluster getRedisCluster(){


    Set<HostAndPort> jedisClusterNode = new HashSet<HostAndPort>();
    jedisClusterNode.add(new HostAndPort("redis-test-cluster1", 6379));

    JedisPoolConfig jedisPoolConfig = new JedisPoolConfig();
    jedisPoolConfig.setMaxTotal(10);
    jedisPoolConfig.setMaxIdle(10);
    jedisPoolConfig.setMaxWaitMillis(10000);
   jedisPoolConfig.setTestOnBorrow(true); 
    JedisCluster jedisCluster = new JedisCluster(jedisClusterNode, 10000, 1,10, "passwordString",jedisPoolConfig);
    return jedisCluster;
}



    public static void main(String[] args) {
    String jsonString = new String("{\"Test1\": \"data1\", \"Test2\": 42}");

    Map<String,String> map = new HashMap<String,String>();
    map.put("testjson",jsonString);

    JedisCluster jedisCluster = new RedisJavaClient().getRedisCluster();
    jedisCluster.hmset("idtest",map);

     String value = jedisCluster.hget("testjson","idtest");
     System.out.println("value passed : "+value);



}
```

And i am getting the below exception :

Exception in thread "main" redis.clients.jedis.exceptions.JedisNoReachableClusterNodeException: No reachable node in cluster
    at redis.clients.jedis.JedisSlotBasedConnectionHandler.getConnection(JedisSlotBasedConnectionHandler.java:69)
    at redis.clients.jedis.JedisSlotBasedConnectionHandler.getConnectionFromSlot(JedisSlotBasedConnectionHandler.java:86)
    at redis.clients.jedis.JedisClusterCommand.runWithRetries(JedisClusterCommand.java:102)
    at redis.clients.jedis.JedisClusterCommand.run(JedisClusterCommand.java:25)
    at redis.clients.jedis.JedisCluster.hmset(JedisCluster.java:513)
    at com.connection.jedisclient.Test.main(Test.java:25)

I am able to set it manually in the cluster as below :

### 127.0.0.1:6379> hmset users jsontest "{\"Test1\": \"data1\", \"Test2\": 42}"

### OK

### 127.0.0.1:6379> hget users jsontest

### "{\"Test1\": \"data1\", \"Test2\": 42}"

Answer (score 0):

Try connecting the same using either localhost or 127.0.0.1 as the HOST

```
public JedisCluster getRedisCluster(){


Set<HostAndPort> jedisClusterNode = new HashSet<HostAndPort>();
jedisClusterNode.add(new HostAndPort("127.0.0.1", 6379));

JedisPoolConfig jedisPoolConfig = new JedisPoolConfig();
jedisPoolConfig.setMaxTotal(10);
jedisPoolConfig.setMaxIdle(10);
jedisPoolConfig.setMaxWaitMillis(10000);
jedisPoolConfig.setTestOnBorrow(true); 
JedisCluster jedisCluster = new JedisCluster(jedisClusterNode, 10000, 1,10, "passwordString",jedisPoolConfig);
return jedisCluster;
}



public static void main(String[] args) {
String jsonString = new String("{\"Test1\": \"data1\", \"Test2\": 42}");

Map<String,String> map = new HashMap<String,String>();
map.put("testjson",jsonString);

JedisCluster jedisCluster = new RedisJavaClient().getRedisCluster();
jedisCluster.hmset("idtest",map);

 String value = jedisCluster.hget("testjson","idtest");
 System.out.println("value passed : "+value);



}
```

Comment: It is a remote linux box. How do i establish a remote connection to it?

Comment: Try using the HOST address(ip) rather than the HOSTName